# React JS how to interconnect input form

Tags: mysql, reactjs, forms, input

I'm creating a web app similar to a classic peer-2-peer lending platform.
In the form to publish the loan request, I connected a slider to the input in which to enter the requested amount.
However, I have two problems: the slider is set with a minimum of $ 100 and a maximum of $ 1000.
I am attaching two screen to better understand:
[image: Before compiling]
[image: Amount >$1000]
By continuing to fill in the form, if you enter an amount greater than that allowed, the default value becomes the previous one, I would like it to be the maximum, that is $ 1000
Furthermore, I would like that the tenor also affects the interest rate, the more time you pay off the loan, the more the interest increases. At the default value of the tenor, ie 6 months, no change. For each increase + 2% and for each decrease -2%.
All these data are then saved in the MySQL table.

Codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/priceless-gould-30uuf?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Do you want `handleSizeBlur` to `setTutorial` or `setSizeInputText`? How should `tenor` affect the interest rate? Please update your question to (1) provide more details for expected behavior, and (2) be more focused, try to limit your question to one specific issue.

Comment: setSizeInputText I think is better. At the default value of the tenor, ie 6 months, no change. For each increase + 2% and for each decrease -2%.

Comment: Can you reproduce your code into a codesandbox and share in your question. I tried this myself but you appear to be using more than material-ui elements so I had to skip some fields and the behavior between the slider and the amount field seems to as you describe, so I suspect I'm not understanding what you want it to do.

Comment: Ok,I'm sorry but I started coding 2 months ago and I'm new on this site too. Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bound the entered loan size value between the min and max values, `Math.max(MIN_VALUE, Math.min(value, MAX_VALUE)`. Compute the new value and update both the slider and tutorial state.

```
const handleSizeBlur = (value) => {
  const newValue = Math.max(MIN_VALUE, Math.min(Number(value), MAX_VALUE));
  setSizeInputText(newValue);
  setTutorial(tutorial => ({ ...tutorial, size: newValue }));
};
```

For adding a percentage to the interest rate based on tenor then I suggest to make the option values of [1, 3, 6, 8, 10, 12] months be [-4, -2, 0, 2, 4, 6] percent respectively, with 0 being the default `tenor` value.

```
const initialTutorialState = {
  ...
  tenor: 0, // <-- initialize to 0 (6 months)
  ...
};

...

// Use an effect to update the interest value when size or tenor update
useEffect(() => {
  const interest = `${
    Math.ceil(tutorial.size * X_FACTOR) + Number(tutorial.tenor)
  }%`;

  setTutorial((tutorial) => ({ ...tutorial, interest }));
}, [tutorial.size, tutorial.tenor]);

...

<TextField
  id="standard-read-only-input"
  label="Interest rate"
  defaultValue="25%"
  value={tutorial.interest} // <-- display the interest value from state
  InputProps={{
    readOnly: true
  }}
/>

...

<TextField
  ...
  value={`${
    Math.ceil(tutorial.size * X_FACTOR) +
    Number(tutorial.tenor) // <-- add tenor to computed interest rate
  }%`}
  ...
/>

...

<Form.Control
  ...
  defaultValue={0}
  ...
>
  <option value={-4}>1 month</option> // <-- define tenor select values
  <option value={-2}>3 months</option>
  <option value={0}>6 months</option>
  <option value={2}>8 months</option>
  <option value={4}>10 months</option>
  <option value={6}>12 months</option>
</Form.Control>
```

[image: Edit react-js-how-to-interconnect-input-form]

Comment: Almost everything works, but when I enter the loan value in the input , credit score is not calculated and the slider doesn't move.

Comment: @GinoPino You didn't mention anything about wanting *that* behavior. :p Easy enough to add though. Add a `setTutorial((tutorial) => ({ ...tutorial, size: newValue }));` to the `handleSizeBlur` callback. I updated answer and sandbox.

Comment: But now the form doesn't register my creditscore, before there was value = {tutorial.creditscore}, now value = {`$ {
                       Math.ceil (tutorial.size * X_FACTOR) +
                       Number (tutorial.tenor)
                     }% `} and I don't know how to change it without losing the function.
I know I ask stupid questions, but I'm trying to learn from practice so I lack a lot of theory.
Thanyou very much!

Comment: @GinoPino I checked in both my sandbox and yours, `tutorial.creditscore` isn't updated anywhere. It is defined in the initial data `initialTutorialState`, copied into a new data object in `saveTutorial`, and set back in state in the `TutorialDataService.create` call in `saveTutorial`. Was there supposed to be something that updates `creditscore` in the form?

Comment: I'm sorry I was wrong. I wanted to write value = {tutorial.interest} , is the interest rate that is not saved in the form and sent to my database.

Comment: @GinoPino Updated answer and sandbox. Use an effect hook to update interest state when size or tenor update.